# Unfurl links as videos in Slack

Tags: slack, oembed, video-embedding

"Slack" can unfurl links as videos, but some services can and some cannot.

Vimeo(https://vimeo.com/) can unfurl links as videos in Slack.

TED(https://www.ted.com/talks) cannot unfurl links as videos in Slack.

Their's HTML have oembed links as <link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="https://example.com/...
And They have embed video player.

reference: https://oembed.com/

What is their's difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Slack support:

> Unfurling of inline videos is made possible by allowlisting specific
> partner domains. Currently, there is only a small number of providers
> which unfurl this way in Slack, such as widely adopted services like
> YouTube, Loom and Vimeo. Each has been added on a case by case basis.
> We don't have any immediate plans to add further video unfurls such as
> this

Comment: So it's basically handpicked by slack. It's funny loom screenshots don't unfurl even though their videos do (the URL pattern is different, so I guess they look at more than just the domain itself).